# If $p$ is prime , solve $a^2 -b^2=p$ for $a,b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For $a^2-b^2=p$, with form $ax+by=c$ with $x,y$ being integer variables & $(a,b)\mid c, x=a, y=b$. 
 So, the $\gcd$ of $(a,b) =p$, with the Bezout's coefficients being $x=a,y=b$.

This value $p$ is in geometrical terms the intercept of the straight line $ax + by = p$ with $x=a, y=b$.

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem in your question title?

Comment: @Arthur  Cannot understand, yes the question is :solve given $p$ is prime, and $a^2-b^2=p$ for $a,b$.

Comment: @jitender $a^2-b^2$ can be factorised as $(a+b)(a-b)$. Since $p$ is prime, the only factors are $1$ and $p$. If $a+b=1$, and $a-b=p$ (or the other way around), what happens when you add them together?

Comment: @TobyMak Why need to add them up to get $2a= p+1$ is not clear. So, you mean that is the answer, i.e. $a= \frac{p+1}{2}$. Similarly, $b= \frac{p-1}{2}$.

Comment: @jitender Then $a = \frac{p+1}{2}$. Substitute this into any of the two equations to find $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bezout's doesn't say that *all* linear combinations of two integers equal the gcd, only that there *exists* a linear combination that equals the gcd. Just because there is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ which equals $p$ doesn't mean that $p$ is the gcd of $a$ and $b$.

Take $5, 3$ for instance. $5^2-3^2 = 16$, but $16\neq \gcd(5, 3)$.

As for the question itself, try this approach: Since $p$ is prime, we have that $a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ is prime. What does that tell us about the two numbers $a+b$ and $a-b$?

Comment: That they are co-prime with one being $p$, and other being $1$. So, given that $a,b$ can be anything (positive, negative), so it is possible that any of the two can be $p$ and the other $1$.

Comment: @jitender You forgot the possibility that one of them is $-1$ and the other is $-p$. But yes, that is true. you will get multiple solutions. However, it should not come as a surprise since, for instance, if $p = 3$ then $a = 2, b = 1$ solves the problem, but so does $a = -2, b = 1$ or $a = 2, b = -1$ or $a = -2, b = -1$.

Comment: Thanks for that. So, need to consider both values $\pm p$:- (i) for $p$, it yields : $a= \frac{p+1}{2}, b= \frac{p-1}{2}$, & vice-versa as $a+b$ and $a-b$ can alternate in value;  (ii) for $-p$, it yields : $a= \frac{-p-1}{2}, b= \frac{-p+1}{2}$, and vice-versa.

Comment: @jitender Almost, but not quite. For instance, for $+p$, the possibilities are $a = \frac{p+1}{2}$ and $b = \pm\frac{p-1}{2}$. You can't swap $a$ and $b$ around, since we must have $|a|>|b|$. But since the problem itself never tells us anything about $a$ or $b$ directly, but only $a^2$ and $b^2$, we don't know the sign of either of them, and therefore the sign can be changed freely and still give a solution.

Comment: I agree that you are correct when stating that $|a|\gt |b|$, & the four solutions for $a,b$ are : $2,1; -2,-1; 2,-1; -2,1$ for $p=3$. But, I erred in swapping values for $a,b$ in my earlier comment, and hence restricted to only two valid combinations of pairs of values of $a,b$. The correct answer should be to swap the conditions for values of $a+b, a-b$, i.e. both (i) $a-b=1 \wedge a+b=p$, & (ii) $a-b = -1 \wedge a+b = -p$ yield on swapping one additional value; & a total of $4$ values- all of which are valid on the given criteria of $|a|\gt |b|$.